# How to grip the dumbbell in french press, so I apply even force in both hands?

Tags: form, grip

I want to do [french press exercise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lying_triceps_extensions), I want to use 1 [dumbbell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dumbbell).

Note: It doesn't matter to this question if the exercise is done lying , or sitting, it's the same issue for both.

I'm interested in the following problem: When gripping the dumbbell my hands are necessarily in a asymmetrical position, there is no way to grip symmetrically as far as I know (you can provide me counterexamples). So the problem is, the force done by each arm and hand could be really different, how to minimize this difference? Grip very strong with my hands? Alternate hand task left and right every new series?

Another option is use a barbell in which then I can position my hands symmetrically, and thus the problem is gone, or to use two dumbbells, one for each hand.

Note 2: [This guy](https://youtu.be/YbX7Wd8jQ-Q?t=48s)(this is a timestamp, you need to see 10 seconds of the video only) has a dumbbell with weights with large diameter, so he can position his hand in [hand triangle](https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=hand%20triangle&espv=2&biw=1517&bih=708&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimhbDJmsLSAhUDEZAKHW2PDlEQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=b-thew8UyR_JmM:), which seems a good grip, do you agree?

Comment: You answered your own question in note 2. Use a 'hand triangle'.

Comment: @JJosaur The problem is that the dumbbells in some gyms have diameter too small for that. The only way is to put one hand front and one back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite right: some dumbbells are too small to allow a triangle hold, so the hands must overlap.  When the hands overlap to a significant extent, it's difficult (impossible?) to tell whether the arms are providing equal forces.

It such cases, I would consider using an EZ-Curl bar or a fixed-weight bar instead of a dumbbell.  You can space your hands on opposite sides of the center of the bar, with perhaps two hand-widths of bare bar between your hands.  When you do a French press with this set-up, unequal forces from the arms will cause noticeable rotation of the bar, which you can correct as you move.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18250)

Comment: You're right, @Alec.  I have expanded/substantiated the answer.

Comment: Nice! Looks a bit more helpful now.

Comment: @CCCV At least this ensures the force is the same, wich is important in the exercise! Of course, this is unconfortable to do in the gym becauses it takes more space and it uses a equipment more rare (there are less EZ bars than dumbells) but it solves the equal force problem, wich is wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

> ### Standing Unilateral Dumbbell Tricep Extensions

[image]

> ### Lying Unilateral Dumbbell Tricep Extensions

[image]

*Source: weighttraining.guide*

Comment: Thank you for contributing, though, in my post I'm referencing the same exercise you picture, but with two hand grip instead of one, that is to say, working both triceps in each arm. The title is clear in this, it says: "How to grip the dumbbell in french press, so I apply even force in both hands?". I hope you don't feel bad about this, cheers!

Comment: Oh my mistake.  I saw the comment " The problem is that the dumbbells in some gyms have diameter too small for that." -- sounded like a triangle hand grip wouldn't work for you.  I agree with CCCV's answer that being the case.